# How to apply a mask to a qwebview in PyQt?

Tags: pyqt4, pyside, pyside2

I'm trying with QWebView.mask() in PyQt4 or PySide or PySide2, for convert the transparent pixels of a transparent QWebView into a window mask, like a frameless window with custom shape, but not work, the window is translucent.

```
webview = QtWebKit.QWebView()
mask = webview.mask()
webview.setMask(mask)
```

Why this not work, what alternatives exist and how i can solve this?

note: I'm trying with QWidget too, and still not works.

```
widget = QtGui.QWidget()
mask = widget.mask()
widget.setMask(mask)
```

Something like this: [Using an alpha transparent mask on a QWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594066/using-an-alpha-transparent-mask-on-a-qwidget)

**but for PyQt4, not for Qt, because im working on scripting...**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
webview.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

widget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
```

This is applicable for BOTH, i hope this help you...

Comment: It works for disable mouse events, but not makes the click through the window! :(

Comment: ummmm, sorry maybe you can combine a QPixmap, grabWidget

Comment: how i can do that?