# QPixmap with a transparent part

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

I'm making a simple puzzle game. The piece is a square, and it contains the corresponding part of an image.

What I need to do is to change the shape from the square to the common puzzle shape. I've made a template in Photoshop:

[image: Black corner puzzle piece]

Now, I need to somehow use it as a mask to change the shape of my square piece. I tried the following:

```cpp
QImage temp;
temp.load("://Templates/c1.png");
temp = temp.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Mono);
QBitmap bit;
bit = QBitmap::fromImage(temp);
puz->img.setMask(bit);
```

Where `puzzle->img` is my square piece.

It works, but I get "rough corners" in the connectors. I suppose all semi-transparent pixels become fully filled with a color (or fully transparent?), so that's why it doesn't look smooth.

How do I make it smoother?

I tried a different approach: since `setAlphaChannel()` is an obsolete function, documentation says that I need to use `QPainter::CompositionMode`. I tried the following

```cpp
void puzzle::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget )
{
   painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
   painter->fillRect(x, y, 90, 90, Qt::transparent);
   painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);
   painter->drawPixmap(x, y, 90, 90, img);
   painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);
   painter->drawImage(x,y, mask);
}
```

It works like that in [Image Composition example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-imagecomposition-example.html), but I get black pixels instead of transparent in my project:

[image]

`mask` initialization:

```
mask.load("://Templates/c1.png");
mask = mask.scaled(90, 90, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
mask = mask.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setAlphaChannel` instead. A mask only has values of 0 and 1 while the alpha channel should allow 256 variations in transparency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Documentation doesn't suggest to use `setAlphaChannel`. I tried another approach, but still have some problems (see UPDATE: section).

Comment: Have you tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594066/using-an-alpha-transparent-mask-on-a-qwidget#7594160 ?

Comment: It's similar to what I've tried. If I add `painter.fillRect(resultImage.rect(), Qt::white);` (or any other color) with `QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationOver` at the end of `void puzzle::paint`, it works fine - I see my piece with my template shape, the rest is filled with chosen color. However, if I use `Qt::transparent` it shows as black.